# How to find circles in HTML images and register a hover event?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas

I have this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhOkD.jpg I want to detect the circles/ovals and register a mouseover event and show a tooltip over it. I have search over the internet but nothing relevant found.

Comment: Does this colors always have the same color? Or are the lines always black and the background white?

Comment: @Joriktos yes there are limited colors.

Comment: @markE are you missing a link?

Comment: The map-element was created to create hotspots on your images ...  and here's an online tool to add the tooltips: http://www.inabrains.com/tooltip/image-hotspot-creator.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code loops through each pixel of the image and detects the defined RGB-colors (in this case your green and for example also the "really black" pixels, there are also some "lighter" black pixels which aren't detected, because the difference is set to 10).
If you want to see the detected pixels, you can set the newColor-key.

I hope this helps you, but i think so. Now someone could also add a function to detect areas, not each pixel, or something like this. But I think with this code you can do what you want.

Here you can find it on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b5gnddt4/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var canvas = $('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas[0].getContext( '2d' );

    var img = new Image;
    img.crossOrigin = '';
    img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/xG8sIPp.jpg';
    img.onload = function() {
        var width = img.width;
        var height = img.height;
        canvas.attr( 'width', width );
        canvas.attr( 'height', height );

        setTimeout( function() {
            ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, width, height );
            ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0, width, height );
            img.remove();

            canvas.setHover([
                {
                    color: [ 121, 145, 71, 255 ],
                    newColor: [ 255, 0, 0, 255 ],            // you can set this to show the detected area
                    difference: 36,                          // the color/alpha values can have a difference of 36
                    func: function() {                       // this is called on hover of the detected points
                      canvas.css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );
                      console.log( this );
                    }
                },
                {
                    difference: 10,
                    color: [ 0, 0, 0, 255 ],
                    func: function() {
                        console.log( this );
                    }
                }
            ]);
        });
    };
});

$.fn.setHover = function( options ) {
    var canvas = this;
    var ctx = this[0].getContext( '2d' );
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData( 0, 0, this.width(), this.height() );
    var rgbaData = imgData.data;
    var hover = [];

    for( var i = 0; i < rgbaData.length; i += 4 ) {
        $.each( options, function() {
            if( rgbaData[i + 0] - this.difference < this.color[0] && rgbaData[i + 0] + this.difference > this.color[0] &&
                rgbaData[i + 1] - this.difference < this.color[1] && rgbaData[i + 1] + this.difference > this.color[1] &&
                rgbaData[i + 2] - this.difference < this.color[2] && rgbaData[i + 2] + this.difference > this.color[2] &&
                rgbaData[i + 3] - this.difference < this.color[3] && rgbaData[i + 3] + this.difference > this.color[3]
            ) {
                // x-Coord: (i / 4) % canvas.width()
                // y-Coord: Math.floor((i / 4) / canvas.width())
                if( !hover[(i / 4) % canvas.width()] ) hover[(i / 4) % canvas.width()] = [];
                hover[(i / 4) % canvas.width()].push({
                    y: Math.floor((i / 4) / canvas.width()),
                    props: this
                });
                if( this.newColor ) {
                    rgbaData[i] = this.newColor[0];
                    rgbaData[i + 1] = this.newColor[1];
                    rgbaData[i + 2] = this.newColor[2];
                    rgbaData[i + 3] = this.newColor[3];
                }
            }
        });
    }

    imgData.data = rgbaData;
    ctx.putImageData( imgData, 0, 0 );

    canvas.on( 'mousemove', function( event ) {
        if( hover[event.offsetX || event.originalEvent.layerX] ) {
            $.each( hover[event.offsetX || event.originalEvent.layerX], function( i, data ) {
                if( data.y === (event.offsetY || event.originalEvent.layerY) ) {
                    data.props.func();
                    return false;
                } else {
                    noHover();
                }
            });
        } else {
            noHover();
        }
    });

    function noHover() {
      // close Tooltip, or do something else
      canvas.css( 'cursor', '' );
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: That is great! Can I register a jquery tooltip library as well?

Comment: Thank you, was a lot of work, but I had also a lot of fun with it ;)
And yes, you can, i think. I'll edit my post. If this is the answer you wanted to have, then please mark it as accepted answer, thank you ;)

Comment: Okay, you can use the jquery tooltip library, but it's really buggy... You should code your own tooltip ;) http://jsfiddle.net/b5gnddt4/3/

Comment: Thanks again! I'll adjust the tooltip.

Comment: I don't really know what you exactly want.

Comment: I have managed to fix the tooltip. What I want now is if there are 2 - 3 colors of circles I want to add tooltip for each of the colors.